# How to create a query and get the result from the query in Zend 1?

Tags: sql, zend-framework

I'm trying to make in View a query ,execute it and get the result  . 
This is my try :

```
$last_id = $_COOKIE['last_id'];
//if (isset($last_id)){
$db = new Zend_Db_Table('order_products_names'); //the table name
$query = "select * from order_products_names where order_id = '$last_id'";
$query = $db->query($query);
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    echo $row['names'];
}
```

obviously it not works. Can someone help me with this ?
I tried also this version:

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'lunchbox_live',
                'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'dbname'   => 'order_products_names',
                'adapterNamespace' => 'MyProject_Db_Adapter'
));
 $last_id = $_COOKIE['last_id'];
 $dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
 $query = $dbAdapter->query("select * from order_products_names where order_id = '$last_id'";
```

This happens when this line (`$query = $dbAdapter->query("select * from order_products_names where order_id = '$last_id'";`) of code is commented : 
[image]
and this happens when is NOT commented : 
[image]

Comment: anyone who knows zend ?

Comment: have you something in $dbAdapter?

Comment: hi again @doydoy44 i updated my post, please check it out

Comment: Have you something in $dbAdapter? :) (with var_dump)

Comment: yes, i have smth like this : bject(Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql)#230 (12) { ["_pdoType":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["_numericDataTypes":protected]=> array(16) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2) ["INT"]=> int(0) ["INTEGER"]=> int(0) ["MEDIUMINT"]=> int(0) ["SMALLINT"]=> int(0) ["TINYINT"]=> int(0) ["BIGINT"]=> int(1) ["SERIAL"]=> int(1) ["DEC"]=> int(2) ["DECIMAL"]=> int(2) ["DOUBLE"]=> int(2) ["DOUBLE PRECISION"]=> int(2) ["FIXED"]=> int(2) ["FLOAT"]=> int(2) }  ..........

Comment: ok.:) have you datas in $query->fetchAll() (with var_dump())?

Comment: if I do a var_dump to $query , it didn't display the var_dump result and all of the design it messed up. I don't know if you understand me :)

Comment: sorry, i was changed the question : var_dump($query->fetchAll());

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50672/discussion-between-doydoy44-and-chester)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$row = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM order_products_names where order_id = '". $last_id . "'");
echo $row['names'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way to do things, but just to answer your question, try something like this:

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'lunchbox_live',
                'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'dbname'   => 'order_products_names',
                'adapterNamespace' => 'MyProject_Db_Adapter'
));

$last_id = $_COOKIE['last_id'];
$stmt = $db->query("select * from order_products_names where order_id = ?", array($last_id)); 
$products = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($products as $product)
{
//....
}
```

Comment: can you invite me for chat ?